# How can i disable reverse path filter rp_filter in mac

Tags: networking, routing, mac-osx, ethernet, reverse-engineering

I am following this

[Ubuntu Linux - two interfaces, same subnet, different vlan - MAC/ARP issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/368085/ubuntu-linux-two-interfaces-same-subnet-different-vlan-mac-arp-issues)

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1/102.rp_filter=0
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1/103.rp_filter=0
```

But this is not working on mac. it gives  `net: class is not implemented`

How can do it in mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is in RFC3704. Apple is a BSD based OS and still has a fair amount different then Linux. In BSD they don't keep this setting in the kernel but in PF.  From what I can tell Apple is assuming that everything is in an environment where routing is symmetric.

The particular setting is done using the urpf-failed keyword in filter rules:

```
block in quick from urpf-failed label uRPF
```

You are going to want to replace that with:

```
pass in quick from urpf-failed label uRPF
```

Apple doesn't make this easy or obvious. Your going to have mess with URPF to make this happen. The easiest way to mess with PF on a Mac is to use Icefloor (http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/) or Murus (http://www.murusfirewall.com) I am not in a position to test this. But hopefully this points you in the right direction.